# Proving functions equality is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification

The reason I am posting this is that these seem too trivial and my "proofs" feel like I am doing nothing other than stating definitions, not even manipulating them.

Here is how functions equality is defined in the book:

> Two functions $f : X → Y$ ,$g: X→ Y$ with the same domain and range are said to be equal, $f=g$, if and only if $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x ∈ X$. (If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ agree for
>   some values of $x$, but not others, then we do not consider $f$ and $g$ to be equal.)

My work:

Reflexive:

Let $f : X → Y$ be a function then by definition for all $x ∈ X$ we have $f(x)=f(x)$ so $f$ is equal to itself.

Symmetric:

Let $f : X → Y$ and $g: X→ Y$ be two functions, if we have $f=g$ then for all $x ∈ X$ we have $f(x)=g(x)$, if every input $x$ of $f$ gives the same output as when this input is put in $g$ then conversely every input $x$ of $g$ gives the same output  as when this input is put in $f$, formally, $x ∈ X$ we have $g(x)=f(x)$, thus $g=f$ and the notion of function equality is symmetric.

Transitive:

Let $f : X → Y$ and $g: X→ Y$ and $h: X→ Y$ be three functions if $f=g$ and $g=h$, for all $x ∈ X$ we have $f(x)=g(x)$ and for all $x ∈ X$ we have $g(x)=h(x)$ similarly, we can essentially replace $g$ by $f$ as they are equal, so we get $f=h$, thus the notion of function equality is transitive.

Can someone let me know is what I did is correct and if not how to improve it?

Comment: In my opinion, your proofs are going to seem like re-writing definitions with the aim of proving statements. That is all right. However, your language in the second and third parts of the proof makes it seem like you have assumed what you are supposed to prove. The proofs of the second and third parts hinge on the fact that the relation of equality is defined on the set Y. You cannot "explain your way" to proof, as far as the second part is concerned. In the third part, you use the fact that equality is defined over the set Y and thus, for all x, f(x)=h(x), implying that f=h. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For transitivity, you could directly invoke the transitivity of equality. That looks more elegant to me.

You may also want to improve the grammar by splitting up the various run-on sentences into separate bits.

Comment: I thought about this but I wasn't sure I could just say it. 
Noted the thing about grammar. but is what I said enough?

Comment: You just need to say that"for all x, $f(x) = f(x)$ by reflexivity of equality", then "$f(x) = g(x)$ and so $g(x) = f(x)$ by symmetry of equality" and then "$f(x) = g(x)$ and $g(x)=h(x)$ implies $f(x)=h(x)$ by transitivity of equality". It is important to note that "for all $x$" is made note of. A fn is not reflexive unless it applies for all $x$.